# SQL statement to select from 2 different tables, from two different databases (same server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How do I select from multiple tables in different databases on the same server?

Also, Is there a way to have an identifying marker so I could see where the results came from?

So for example:

```
SELECT db1.table1.name, db2.table2.name, fromTbl
FROM db1.table1, db2.table2
WHERE db1.table1.name LIKE '%j%' OR db2.table2.name LIKE '%j%'
```

So in this case, I'm selecting the names from 2 different databases and tables. I'm doing a wildcard search on those names and the fromTbl would let me know where the results came from?

```
4    john smith    4    555.555.5555    table1
17   joe schmoe    17   555.555.5555    table2
11   james doe     11   555.555.5555    table1
```

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: like is a worse habit than select a,b,c from d join e on d.x = e.x and its use is discouraged.  Damien you should use >= "j" for searches.

Comment: you lost me there danny... what if i'm doing a search for say, United Parcel, what then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a UNION ALL and add in the database name like:

```
SELECT [columns_list], 'db1.schema.table1.name' AS [fromTbl]
FROM db1.schema.table1
WHERE db1.schema.table1.name LIKE '%j%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT [columns_list], 'db2.schema.table2.name' AS [fromTbl]
FROM db2.schema.table2
WHERE db2.schema.table2.name LIKE '%j%'
```

This will only work if the columns in the tables have the same column types (as your example suggests) else UNION will not work.

Comment: How would i go about searching 3 different tables? Do I use union twice?

Comment: Yes you can use union many times, apparently there is no limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676970/sql-server-whats-the-limit-on-number-of-unions

Answer (score 1):

Doing a union seems like your best bet here.  A union will combine the results of two queries.

```
select name, 'table1' as fromTbl
from db1.schema.table1
where name like '%j%'

union --or union all depending on what you want

select name, 'table2' as fromTbl
from db2.schema.table2
where name like '%j%'
```

Comment: How would i go about searching 3 different tables? Do I use union twice?

Comment: You should also think if you need to use "union" or "union all". The difference is that union tries to remove duplicate rows from different queries.

Answer (score -1):

try this:
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=YOUR SERVER;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SELECT * FROM Table1') AS a 
UNION
 SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=ANOTHER SERVER;Trusted_Connection=yes;','SELECT * FROM Table1') AS a