# SQL Server select data from 100+ tables

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a database which contains 100+ tables with data from sensors; one table for each sensor. And using 100+ `union all` is not good. So, is there a better way to collect data from all tables with maximum profit?

Comment: You don't have much choice other than `union all`, so use it.

Comment: Any particular reason why you have one table per sensor?

Comment: Why on earth do you have one table per sensor?  Why can't you use UNION ALL? Are you able to change anything about the structure? Could you, even temporarily, create a holding table to insert all your data into prior to use?

Comment: I did not create this structure, and I can not change it. So, if only `union all` is best way, I will use it.

Comment: Create a view with "union all" inside and then use it as a table

Comment: Presuming that the tables have a similar naming convention, you could write a stored procedure to select from sys.tables where name matches pattern, insert those into a temp table, and select from that.

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have pointed out, `union all` (optionally packed into a view) is the only solution here.

However, it is better to acquaint yourself with [certain caveats and limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33496840/3925232) that SQL Server imposes on queries with numerous `union` statements. With luck, your company might eventually hit one of those limits, which might force the management to reconsider the approach to the database design.